# Receiving an object reference not set to an instance error - Dynamics CRM 2011 plugin with LINQ

Tags: c#, object, reference, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have the following code:

```
var retrievedProducts = (from p in orgcontext.ProductSet
join qd in orgcontext.QuoteDetailSet
on p.ProductId equals qd.sp_SellingProductId.Id
where qd.QuoteId.Id == entity.Id
select new
{
    product_name = p.orb_ParentProductid.Name
}).Distinct();

var _txttowrite = "";
if (retrievedProducts != null)
{
    //for each item returned write the output to a string.

    foreach (var item in retrievedProduct)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_txttowrite))
        {
            _txttowrite = item.product_name;
        }
        else
        {
             _txttowrite += ", " + item.product_name;
        }                                
    }
}
```

All seems to work up until it gets to the foreach (var item in retrievedProducts) line, so I have updated it to :

```
foreach (var item in retrievedProducts.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.product_name != null).Select(a => a))
```

but am now receiving an object reference not set to an instance of an object error and I must admit I am out of my depth here with this.

The problem is caused by the query returning a null value so I need a way to remove these nulls either in the original query or a subsequent one.

Comment: Think this is fixed now, changed line product_name = p.orb_ParentProductid.Name to product_name = p.orb_ParentProductid.Name and then checked this for not null with if (item.product_name != null) and this as I said appears to work, I presume it is due ot the field being a lookup?